# Python: how to print instance variable of type string

Tags: python

I am trying to print a string variable returned by name() function, which in this case should print "Jim, but Python is printing

```
      `<bound method Human.name of <__main__.Human object at 0x7f9a18e2aed0>>`
```

Below is the code.

```
class Human:

    def __init__(self):
            name = None

    def setName(self, _name):
            name = _name

    def name(self):
            return self.name

jim = Human()
jim.setName("Jim")
print(jim.name())
```

UPDATE:
After reading the answers, i updated the code as shown below, but, now i am getting a new error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

```
class Human:

    def __init__(self):
            self.name = None

    def setName(self, _name):
            self.name = _name

    def name(self):
            return self.name

jim = Human()
jim.setName("Jim")
print(jim.name())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self.name` is the method itself. You have no attributes storing the `name`. Nowhere do you actually set the name as an attribute. The following works:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def setName(self, _name):
        self.name = _name

    # NOTE: There is no more name method here!
```

Now you have an actual attribute, and you don't need to call the method here:

```
jim = Human()
jim.setName("Jim")
print(jim.name)  # directly using the attribute
```

You could even just set the attribute directly:

```
jim = Human()
jim.name = "Jim"
print(jim.name)
```

Alternatively, use `self._name` to store the name on the instance:

```
class Human:
    _name = None

    def setName(self, _name):
        self._name = _name

    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

Here we used a *class* attribute `Human._name` as a default, and only set `self._name` on the instance in the `Human.setName()` method.

Comment: i declared the variable "name" in my constructor

Comment: @Jimm: that is just a local variable, not an attribute on the instance.

Comment: After making the changes you suggested, print(jim.name()) is giving error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Read the rest of my answer carefully :-)

Comment: I dont understand your why you declared a class level variable `_name` and how is it related to my error.

Comment: The error in your question is caused by you misunderstanding how attributes on instances work; there is no `name` attribute on your instance so Python looks to the class instead. There it finds the `name` method instead.

Comment: In `__init__` and `setName` you never actually set attributes; you only have local variables. If you *did* set `self.name` you would mask the `Human.name()` method and your code would still break.

Comment: The solution is to not use the same names for methods and instance attributes. Hence the choice of `_name` as the attribute name. But since Python will look at the class if an instance does not have a requested attribute, we can set a default on the class.

Comment: In other words: I am showing you alternative ways to solve the problem, hopefully giving you additional insights into how this all works.

Comment: I thought the WAY To declare an instance level variable is through a constructor AND That is why i declared `self.name = None` in the constructor. How can i declare instance level variable

Comment: You don't *have* to declare attributes. Python doesn't declare any names; assignment is all you need. But if you set attributes on an instance *with the same name* as attributes in the class then `jim.name` no longer finds the method but the instance attribute instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `name` is the name of the internal variable in your object and also the name of the method.

The namespace for variables and methods is the same.  Change the name of your method to something other than `name`.  This will fix your getter.  On first glance I thought that that would be all you have to do, but the recommendation in Martijn's answer also applies -- you need to assign to self.name and not just name in order to get your setter to work as well.

As an aside, this getter/setter pattern is not usually appropriate for Python.  You should ask yourself why you want to use a getter/setter pattern over simply accessing the object's variable directly.  [See the section on getters and setters in this article](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setter and getter properties instead of your custom defined methods.

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name
```

And then, use them:

```
jim = Human()
jim.name = "Jim"
print(jim.name)
```